# Kohana ORM Print if empty

Tags: orm, kohana

Lets say I have the following:

```
$categories = ORM::factory('category')->find_all();
foreach ($categories as $category) :
echo $category->category_title;
foreach ($category->posts->find_all() as $post) :
echo $post->post_title; 
endforeach;
endforeach;
```

It prints:

```
Category One
Post One
Category Two

Category Three
Post Two
Category Four
Post Three
```

The gap means there is no post there.

What I want it to print is:

```
Category One
Post One
Category Two
No Post
Category Three
Post Two
Category Four
Post Three
```

So basically I want:

```
foreach ($posts->find_all() as $post) :
if post exists
echo $post->post_title; 
else
No Post
endforeach;
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Edit to include categories to better picture what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Kohana 3.2 and ORM.

Check out the guide: [http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/using](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/using#check-that-orm-loaded-a-record)

There is a section called **Check that ORM loaded a record**

```
if ($post->loaded())
{
    echo $post->post_title;
}
else
{
    echo 'No Post';
}
```

Including the categories from the updated question:

```
$categories = ORM::factory('category')->find_all();
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    $posts = $category->posts->find_all();
    if (count($posts) > 0)
    {
        echo $category->category_title;
        foreach ($posts as $post)
        {
            echo $post->post_title; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'No Posts';
    }
}
```

Comment: During my Google searches I did try this, but it never prints No Post.

Comment: It probably doesn't print the posts because the category doesn't have any posts. You should add a check to see if $category->posts->find_all() actually has posts